# Adding alt attribute to image in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, alt

I want to know how to add alt attribute to an image in javascript, below is my code...

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.src='../../KY/images/common/buttons/browseIcon.png';
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27):

You have two ways : you can use either [alt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLImageElement) property

```
image.alt = "Your text here"
```

or [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute) method

```
image.setAttribute("alt","Your text here");
```

Comment: "image.setAttribute("alt","Your text here");" worked perfectly for what I needed. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Above mentioned methods would not work when u create buttons or any other element in dom javascript, and for this use the below mentioned method

```
control.setAttribute("title","your tooltip value")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the [alt property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLImageElement).